# jQuery plugin with Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

What's a simple jQuery plugin that will draw a map given an address?

*I don't need any controls, no panning/zooming.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really don't need any panning/zooming I would use the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) instead. Much nicer to just load an image than all of the GMaps JavaScript.

Comment: Ptrin, you were so right.  Implemented in less than 5 minutes.  Great.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to drawing library you can use [Processing.js Library](http://processingjs.org/)